ViewAsWebPage link not working (but with some nice improvements ! )
Hope I could find some help here regarding the VAWP link, thanks in advance for taking the time reading me. We are currently using data extensions that are regularly updated by automations for sends. We use these data extensions with the user-initiated send in Email Studio and simply drag and drop the DE.
We would like to continue using this process if possible.
We have integrated an AMP script that retrieves the website source from the send log when the link is clicked. The records are correctly recorded in the send log.
I suspect a typo in the below code.
FYI SwG_Website_Source__c represent the ISO code or local
I've already checked the following ressources and couldn't find the answer I'm looking for :

Lookup to Sendlog not working
VAWP links break for Salesforce Send Emails
Building a custom VAWP page for emails
How can I write a VAWP link to a sendlog DE in Salesforce Marketing Cloud
VAWP link breaks intermittently with 'System is temporarily Unavailable'

My question: For some time now, it seems that some of our VAWP links are not working, and some are. However, we are using the sendlog all the time to collect the website source. Could there be an error in this code? Thank you.
This is the code regarding the VAWP :
SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
Set @TimeofSend = Getsendtime()
SET @_IsTestSend = _IsTestSend

IF @_IsTestSend == false THEN

    IF _MessageContext == "VAWP" THEN
        /* Retrieve data from SendLog_In_Use */
        SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
        SET @jobID = jobid

        /* Using the JobID and SubscriberKey to look up the view_email_url */
        SET @SendLogDE = 'SendLog_In_Use'
        SET @lookupLogs = LookupRows(@SendLogDE, "PersonContactID", @subscriberkey, "JobID", @jobID)
        SET @rowCountS = RowCount(@lookupLogs)
        IF @rowCountS > 0 THEN
            SET @rowS = row(@lookupLogs, 1)
            SET @SwG_Website_Source__c = field(@rowS,"SwG_Website_Source__c")
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        /* Set template email behavior for other contexts */
        SET @SwG_Website_Source__c = AttributeValue("SwG_Website_Source__c")
    ENDIF

ELSE

    set @SwG_Website_Source__c = AttributeValue("SwG_Website_Source__c")

ENDIF

and this is the full code :
    %%[

VAR @LogoHeaderLink
VAR @WebviewText
VAR @service_1_link 
VAR @st1
VAR @service_2_link
VAR @st2
VAR @service_3_link
VAR @st3
VAR @facebook_url
VAR @instagram_url
VAR @tiktok_url
VAR @twitter_url
VAR @youtube_url
VAR @pinterest_url 
VAR @PrivacyPolicyLink
VAR @PrivacyPolicyText
VAR @UnsubscribeLink
VAR @UnsubscribeText
VAR @LegalMention
VAR @FooterLogoLink
VAR @jobID
VAR @I
VAR @_IsTestSend

VAR @rowsS, @rowS, @rowCountS
VAR @rows, @row, @rowCount

SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
Set @TimeofSend = Getsendtime()
SET @_IsTestSend = _IsTestSend

IF @_IsTestSend == false THEN

    IF _MessageContext == "VAWP" THEN
        /* Retrieve data from SendLog_In_Use */
        SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
        SET @jobID = jobid

        /* Using the JobID and SubscriberKey to look up the view_email_url */
        SET @SendLogDE = 'SendLog_In_Use'
        SET @lookupLogs = LookupRows(@SendLogDE, "PersonContactID", @subscriberkey, "JobID", @jobID)
        SET @rowCountS = RowCount(@lookupLogs)
        IF @rowCountS > 0 THEN
            SET @rowS = row(@lookupLogs, 1)
            SET @SwG_Website_Source__c = field(@rowS,"SwG_Website_Source__c")
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        /* Set template email behavior for other contexts */
        SET @SwG_Website_Source__c = AttributeValue("SwG_Website_Source__c")
    ENDIF

ELSE

    set @SwG_Website_Source__c = AttributeValue("SwG_Website_Source__c")

ENDIF

SET @rows = LookupRows("ent.Data_Master_Template_Markets","SwG_Website_Source__c", @SwG_Website_Source__c) 
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

IF  @rowCount > 0 THEN 
    FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO 
        SET @row = row(@rows, @i) 

        SET @LogoHeaderLink = field(@row,"lg_logo_header_link")  
        SET @WebviewText = field(@row,"lg_webview_text") 
        SET @st1 = field(@row,"lg_service_1_text") 
        SET @service_1_link = field(@row,"lg_service_1_link") 
        SET @st2 = field(@row,"lg_service_2_text") 
        SET @service_2_link = field(@row,"lg_service_2_link") 
        SET @st3 = field(@row,"lg_service_3_text") 
        SET @service_3_link = field(@row,"lg_service_3_link") 
        SET @facebook_url = field(@row,"lg_facebook_url")
        SET @instagram_url = field(@row,"lg_instagram_url")
        SET @tiktok_url = field(@row,"lg_tiktok_url")
        SET @twitter_url = field(@row,"lg_twitter_url")
        SET @youtube_url = field(@row,"lg_youtube_url")
        SET @pinterest_url = field(@row,"lg_pinterest_url")
        SET @PrivacyPolicyLink = field(@row,"lg_privacy_policy_link")
        SET @PrivacyPolicyText = field(@row,"lg_privacy_policy_text")
        SET @UnsubscribeLink = field(@row,"lg_unsubscribe_link")
        SET @UnsubscribeText = field(@row,"lg_unsubscribe_text")
        SET @LegalMention = field(@row,"lg_legal_mention")
        SET @FooterLogoLink = field(@row,"lg_footer_logo_link")
        SET @UnsubscribeURL = 'https://cloud.communication.XXXXXXXXX.com/unsubscribe'
        SET @FinalUnsubscribeURL = concat(@UnsubscribeURL,"?subscriberkey=", @subscriberkey, "&TimeofSend=", @TimeofSend, "&websiteSource=", @SwG_Website_Source__c")

    NEXT @i 

ELSE 
    RaiseError("Market Excluded", true)
ENDIF 

]%%

Many thanks for your help.

Here are a few updates.
The above code was correct. So theoretically, this was enough to make the VAWP link functional at any moment.
However, we had a %%=contentblockbyid()=%% function, calling a block that was causing some trouble in the code.
